# Using the indefinite article before "rain"

Tags: indefinite-articles, uncountable-nouns

I have recently learned the use of the indefinite article before uncountable nouns to talk about an unspecific instance. Can I use "a heavy rain" in the following sentence to communicate that I am talking about an instance of heavy rain (a heavy downpour)?

> The water level in the lake is much higher after **a** heavy rain.

Comment: Yes, you can. Dictionary.com gives this definition of "rain": _a rainfall, rainstorm,or shower_: "We had **a light rain** this afternoon."

Comment: Your example is perfectly normal and idiomatic.

Comment: You may find the answers to [“ Sound of a heavy rain” vs. “Sound of heavy raining”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/156832/9161) on [ell.se] interesting. (And maybe this one too: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/208559/9161)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rain may be countable or uncountable:

> 1988   R. Rendell Veiled One (1989) xiv. 188   *Rain was streaming down the window, making the glass opaque.*

> 2006   Africa News (Nexis) 27 Mar.   *The current Inter-Tropical Convergence Zone (ITCZ) south of the Equator is likely to bring about more good rains over the country during the next three weeks.*

"Rain", in common with most weakly uncountable nouns, if preceded by an adjective - a + adjective + rain - then the adjective has a partitive effect:

A noun, when used uncountably, describes a set of homogeneous items. However, that set has subsets (i.e. types), e.g. "A *knowledge* **of French**"; "A **warm** *rain* fell"; "A **deep** *sorrow* affected him", etc.

The use of "a/an" is licensed in a/an's meaning of "one example of"; "a type of".

The OED puts this as

> I. Indicating indefiniteness.
>
> 1. Used in an indefinite noun phrase referring to something not specifically identified (and, frequently, mentioned for the first time) but treated as one of a class: one, some, any (the oneness, or indefiniteness, being implied rather than asserted).
>
> a. **Before a noun denoting an individual object or notion, or denoting an individualized substance, quality, or state, and before a collective noun.**
>
> 1847   H. W. Longfellow Evangeline i. i. 59   *A celestial brightness—a more ethereal beauty.*

Comment: I'd disagree that the availability of the indefinite article proves a count usage. 'He took a real pride in his work' does not accept numerals (*'He took 3 / 7 / a dozen / several real prides in ...'). _This_ is the test used by CGEL, more qualified to speak on grammar than dictionaries (even the best) are.

Answer (score 0):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rain) **doesn't** define *rain* as "a rainfall" and it gives no examples of that usage, though it does define *rains* as "falls of rain".

"**a rain**" is uncommon, especially in the UK, though *a heavy rain* and *a light rain* are not.

Google Books shows *a rain **of*** (eg manna from Heaven) to be more common than just *a rain*. Dickens uses only the former:

> ...desk bespattered with **a rain of** ink. [*Bleak House*]

Though Charlotte Brontë's Jane Eyre has:

> ...the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre, and **a
> rain** so penetrating, that further out-door exercise was now out of the
> question.

A search shows that, even 60 years since he wrote the song, Bob Dylan still owns the phrase *A Hard Rain*, but your "a heavy rain" is certainly public domain.

Answer (score 0):

I do [agree](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=after%20a%20heavy%20rain%2C%20after%20heavy%20rain&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cafter%20a%20heavy%20rain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20heavy%20rain%3B%2Cc0) with @OLd Brixtonian. I just wanted to add that your sentence may mean different things depending on whether you use the article ***a*** or not. And there are many contexts where uses with or without the article are interchangeable.

> The water level in the lake is much higher ***after a heavy rain*** [particular instance or *after every heavy rain*].

> The water level in the lake is much higher ***after heavy rain***. [every time it rains heavily, does not refer to a particular instance]

Compare:

> Swimmers are being warned to stay out of the sea for at least 48 hours
> ***after heavy rain***, due to pollution fears. ([Newstalk](https://www.newstalk.com/news/sea-swimmers-should-stay-out-of-water-for-at-least-48-hours-after-heavy-rain-epa-1193417))

and

> The Met Office has warned there could be some damage to property and travel disruption in the event of ***a heavy rain***. ([express.co.uk](https://www.express.co.uk/news/weather/1317166/met-office-weather-warnings-rain-radar-UK-weather-forecast-weekend))

Usually, ***heavy rain*** (without ***a***) is used more commonly in weather forecasts.

Answer (score 0):

This question is based on an erroneous assumption - that *rain* is **never** countable.

> In many tropical countries the produce of the land in grain or roots, during the whole year, depends upon **one rain** in the spring. (Familiar Letters on Chemistry; Liebig, Justus, Freiherr von; 1843)
>
> In the drought-disaster areas, everyone knew that **one rain** does not break a drought, but farmers and townsfolk alike drew a deep, fresh breath and hoped. (Rain; TIME, 1953)
>
> But since February, most of the county has seen only **two rains** ,
> each registering less than half an inch. (FOCUS ON DROUGHT IN THE
> HEARTLAND; Jim Yardley; Atlanta Journal Constitution, 1996)
>
> Right now, **two rains** into the rainy season, there's enough water
> and food for the group to travel together, but just barely. (Almost
> Human; Mary Roach; National Geographic, April 2008)
>
> Since then, there have been **three rains**, followed instantly by prayers
> of thanks. But now the dry season begins. (Echoes of the Great Dust
> Bowl; Hugh, Sidey; TIME, 1996)

Though the non-count use may be the more common by far, the count use of rain seems well established, even without a modifier. In the right context, it's perfectly natural.

The meaning of rain in the above is simply a single instance of rainfall. From [the American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rain),

> rain
>
> *n.*
>
> 1.
>
> a. Water condensed from atmospheric vapor and falling in drops.
>
> b. A fall of such water; a rainstorm.

Comment: These are indisputably count usages (how frequently encountered, I'd not like to say). But with say 'He/They spoke with a great enthusiasm on workers' rights', as 'He/They spoke with 2 / 7 / several great enthusiasms on workers' rights' is ungrammatical, there is a coupling of the indefinite article with a non-count usage. Possibly 'rain' is in the process of countification ('3 coffees, please').

Comment: Can one speak on workers' rights with multiple enthusiasms? In other contexts, _enthusiasm_ is surely a count noun: _His **enthusiasms** were simple: he liked a good meal, a comfortable bed, and a woman who knew what to do in it._ (Wee Hours; Winter, Ellen; Antioch Review). These seem to be symantically licensed.

Comment: One example doesn't license a usage. There are examples where few  if any have pushed [over?] the boundaries of acceptability: 'She took a pride in her appearance and her deportment'.

Comment: Agreed, however in the case of _rain_, the topic of this discussion, there are legitimate examples of the count use. I'm not debating the existence of non-count nouns.